# How can I make a scroll view that clips to a scroll position in android?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I want to make a horizontal scrollview that clips to the closest scroll object, for example, if I have scroll objects 1,2,3 in the scrollview and the user stops scrolling between 1 and 2, the scrollview should jump to the closest object, is this possible in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with RecyclerView and SnapHelper.

Some good sample for it:

1- [Using SnapHelper in RecyclerView](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8)

2- [Detecting snap changes with Android’s RecyclerView SnapHelper](https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424)